# Laravel Websockets Apache2 ReverseProxy setup

Tags: laravel, apache, websocket, reverse-proxy, laravel-websockets

**Problem**

I am trying to setup a live environment with laravel websockets library behind an apache server.
The Websocket server is running on port `6001` (unreachable from outside).
The Apache VHost is configured for `ws.example.com`

I cannot get the Apache to proxy the `wss://` requests correctly.
The request to `wss://ws.example.com/request/path?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.1.1&flash=false` fails.
(`Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line`)

I think there is a problem with my vhost configuration. Am I missing something? Any advice is appreciated.

**vhost configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ws.example.com
    ServerAlias www.ws.example.com.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/vhost/example.com/domains/ws.example.com/public_html

    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/ws.example.com_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/ws.example.com_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /srv/vhost/example.com/domains/ws.example.com/cgi-bin/

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    RewriteEngine on
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyVia on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:6001/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass               /request/path http://localhost:6001/request/path
    ProxyPassReverse        /request/path http://localhost:6001/request/path

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/path/ws.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/path/ws.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a subdomain for websockets. Then edit your virtualhost configs (Apache 2.4) as below. Use pusher-php-server 5.0.3

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName socket.website.com

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:6001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:6001

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.website.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.website.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

@max: your rewrite rules were the key, also applies when the proxy just forwards the unencrypted traffic and apache is handling ssl to the outside, replacing `wss` with `ws` then - after one day of fiddling its finally working!

edit: not enough reputation for a comment , sorry

Comment: As a tip, posting something as an answer that isn't an answer risks getting downvotes, which will make you lose points and put you even further away from being able to comment